# Multiple index with typescript generics, how?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have some interface:

```
interface A {
    a1: { a11: string };
    a2: { a21: string };
    a3: { a31: string };
}
```

Now, i want to create generic-type - object with index by only some fields on interface `A`.

Pseudo-code:

```
type B<T1 extends keyof A, T2 extends keyof A> = {
    [P in T1]: A[T1];
    [P in T2]: A[T2];
}
```

Example of usage:

```
let var1: B<"a1", "a2"> = { a1: { a11: "Hello" }, a2: { a21: "World" } };
```

Now, `var1` is object with only fields: `a1` and `a2`

How can i do this? Thank you.

Comment: So you want to pick some fields of `A`? Why not just use `Pick`: `Pick<A, 'a1' |'a2' >`

Comment: Can you please add a usage example to your question. That is, how would you like to use type `B`? That would clarify your question and help us answer.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir No, i want to make new object from only some fields of `A`. I have added example to question.

Comment: @arvitaly yes, this is what `Pick` is for. picking some fields from a type `let var1: Pick<A, "a1" | "a2"> = { a1: { a11: "Hello" }, a2: { a21: "World" } };` will work exactly the same as your `B` type. `"a1" | "a2"` means you are picking the fields "a1" and "a2" (I know the syntax is a bit confusing but since mapped type iterate over all members of the union passed in this is the way it works out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining a dedicated mapped type might not be necessary in this case `Pick` will do the job just fine. You can pick several fields from a type using `Pick` not just one:

```
interface A {
    a1: { a11: string };
    a2: { a21: string };
    a3: { a31: string };
} 
// Pick<A, "a1" | "a2"> <=> { a1: { a11: string }, a2: { a21: string } }
let var1: Pick<A, "a1" | "a2"> = { a1: { a11: "Hello" }, a2: { a21: "World" } };
```

If you pick from `A` all the time you can of course define a dedicated type for it, but you will get maximum flexibility by using a single type parameter for the key:

```
type B<TKey extends keyof A> = Pick<A, TKey>
let var1: B<"a1" | "a2"> = { a1: { a11: "Hello" }, a2: { a21: "World" } };
```

I would generally avoid creating new mapped types if we can use the built-in ones (such as `Pick`). While I am a fan of mapped and conditional types your team mates might have trouble reading them. Finding docs on the built-in ones will make it easier for them to understand what's going on.

Also note that your `B` type does not mean the user MUST pick two fields from `A`. Using `never` and unions the user can pick any number of keys from `A`:

```
// pick 2 fields
let var1: B<"a1", "a2"> = { a1: { a11: "Hello" }, a2: { a21: "World" } };
// pick 1 field
let var2: B<"a1", never> = { a1: { a11: "Hello" } };
// pick all 3
let var3: B<"a1" | "a2", "a3"> = { a1: { a11: "Hello" }, a2: { a21: "World" }, a3: { a31: "World" } };
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-universal answer, only for two arguments is:

```
type B<T1 extends keyof A, T2  extends keyof A> = {
    [P in T1 | T2]: A[P];
}
```